# Is the sentence "The trace of an odd number of gamma matrices vanish." correct grammatically?

Tags: grammar

In my textbook it says:

> The trace of an odd number of gamma matrices vanish.

Should it be `vanishes' as the trace is singular?

Comment: Yes, seems to be a mistake. It's common these days for speakers and writers to forget the actual subject of a sentence and to get distracted by the plurals that stand between it and the verb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vanishes. But for the mathematics, surely it should be that the trace of *any product* of an odd number of gamma matrices vanishes.

Comment: Yes I should have written that. The book actually says 

``Trace of an odd number of $\gamma_\mu$'s vanish.''